What causes TRedemptionStreamHelper: reading past EOF error?
I am trying to import the content of a large RSMF file (2.1GB) into a message using the Redemption library, this is the code:
//RDOSession session = ... 
Redemption.RDOMail item = session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("myFile.msg", true) as RDOMail;
item.Import("MyRmsfFile.rsmf",1031);

I get the error "TRedemptionStreamHelper: reading past EOF" at IRDOMail.Import(String Path, Object Type), for smaller files I have no issues, could the size of the file be the problem? Is there an alternative to import the file?

The following may be of interest: What is Outlook Redemption?, Download Redemption, RDOMail (see Import), IImportExport, rdoSaveAsType

Please send a problematic rsmf file to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com. Thanks!
